# Mapping two float fields containing geo langitude and latitude into geo_point in kibana using the AWS ElasticSearch Service Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm building a solution that processes the data from Lambda(Python 2.7) through kinesis stream and firehose to Elastic Search domain. Data is stored in Python dictionary and dumped as a JSON to Kinesis

```
                dataDictionary = {
                "precipitationType": precipitationType,
                "location": location,
                "humidity" : humidity,
                "groundTemp": groundTemp,
                "airTemp": airTemp,
                "windSpeed": windSpeed,
                "windDirection": windDirection,
                "measureDate": parsedMeasureDate,
                "systemDate": systemDate,
                "stationGeoLatitude": stationGeoLatitude,
                "stationGeoLongitude": stationGeoLongitude
            }
            #Push data to AWS Kinesis Stream
            res = kinesis.put_record(StreamName = LocalStreamName,Data=json.dumps(dataDictionary),PartitionKey='systemDate')
```

Process is succesful but in want to display the results on map in
[Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqWAG.png) I only have two float fields and no [geo_point/geohash fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpOSr.png)

I cannot figure out how to map them in AWS ElasticSearch Service. I found some documentation about mapping but I have no idea how to use it inside AWS. Maybe I should pass this data in other way in Python code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use mappings and tell elasticsearch to map your 2 fields as a geo-point location:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

You will have to reindex your data, but first specify your mappings.

You could do it using python client, or post the json mapping manualy:

PUT your_index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've created the geo_point field inside my index, but how can I map data from these two fields into the geo_point? It's blank now :(

Comment: just create a geolocation type in your json as descibe in the document link: like "location": stationGeoLatitude ,stationGeoLongitude or location { "lat": stationGeoLatitude , "lon": stationGeoLongitude  }